# How to increase the precision of integration in Python?

Tags: python, scipy, complex-numbers, numerical-integration

I am solving differential equations in the complex domain with Python. I am using `solve_ivp` from  `scipy.integrate` with the `RK45` method. I have already tested all possible methods for solve_ivp, but I cannot achieve the desired precision. The result is reasonable, but the imaginary part of the result is on the order of `10**(-4)`, and the numeric error seems to be greater than that. Is there any other way to solve a system of complex equations with higher precision?

The part of the code where I solve the differential equations is as follows:

```
omega = 1+1j # exemple

def integrate_origin(k0, w0, rmatch, bkg_func, l, omega, file_eos, r0, metodo): 

    nu0 = bkg_func(ri_TOV)[1]
    p0 = bkg_func(ri_TOV)[2]
    rho0 = bkg_func(ri_TOV)[3]
    gamma0 = bkg_func(ri_TOV)[4]

    u0 = BC(r0, k0, w0, nu0, p0, rho0, gamma0, l, omega, file_eos)

    N = int((rmatch - r0)/dr_pert)

    sol_in = solve_ivp(rhs_FD, [r0, rmatch], u0, method=metodo, t_eval=np.linspace(r0, rmatch, N), args=(l, omega, bkg_func))

    return sol_in
```

(Since the code is extensive, I couldn't include it entirely here. Therefore, just an outline of how I can solve this problem would be enough to help me.)

Comment: The most common cause of this is round-off error.  If you subtract two numbers very close to each other, the result will have a lot of digits but be essentially nonsense.  Have you done this on paper to know if more precision is even possible?

Comment: These are very extensive calculations that I could not do on paper. But I was thinking of using other python integrators to test if at least they gave better results. But I don't know very well functions that accept complex differential equations, only ```solve_ivp```

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the tolerances?

Comment: not yet. How can I do this? Within ```solve_ivp``` I can adjust the tolerance?

Comment: Take a look at the [`solve_ivp` docstring](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html). In particular, see the `rtol` and `atol` parameters.